# Can some Windows folders be configured so that any program which aims to write to them must have a UAC prompt?

Tags: windows, file-permissions, uac

Can some Windows folders be configured such that any program which aims to write to them must have a UAC prompt?

It is not a matter of the program requiring elevated permissions, but Windows realizing that writing to the folder requires an elevated prompt and displaying it.

Comment: Windows and NTFS has a system of file permissions, where you can assign read and write access, but I don't think there is any way to make it display a UAC prompt to give you this choice on the fly, i.e. you would have to configure it beforehand. If you configure something read only and a program attempts to write there the program would raise it's own error message.